# Call an android sdk in Unity

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, wrapper

I have an Android SDK which I need to use it in Unity. I have tried the AndroidJavaClass to call the sdk class and the methods but I don't understand the way I have to call another method in a method with two argumenets.

Here is the implementation in java:

```
 sdkManager = new SdkManager(this, new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(String value) {

        /* Add your actions here.
            *  value will contain the tag (eg. 10101010) if decoding was successful.
            */

        textView.setText(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorUpdate(String errorMessage) {
        /* Add your actions here.
            *  If there was an error, value could contain error related text like "No value detected", etc.
            */
        textView.setText(errorMessage);
    }
});
```

I need to get the value from onUpdate(string value) in Unity.